# How to export to compressed BMP RLE using CorelDRAW/Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, corel-draw, bitmap

I have a problem when exporting to **BMP file with RLE compression** using CorelDRAW X6 & Adobe Photoshop CS6.

CorelDRAW have option exporting to BMP RLE but the output file will not be compressed.

Adobe Photoshop have the option but it's greyed out.

Do you know how to export to BMP RLE using these software or maybe there's other alternative?

P.S. Here's the screenshot CorelDRAW X6 & Photoshop CS6:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your .BMP file with Compress(RLE) in Photoshop if you Change you **Image Mode** to **Indexed Color**

Got To **Image Menu > Mode > Indexed Color**

Accept the Indexed Color option setting (Although you can play with its setting depends on the type of your file and use) then save you file As .BMP. Now you will see the **Compress(RLE) Enabled**. Go ahead, try, It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my day. I need this BMP RLE to use with WinAPI splashscreen to reduce the filesize of BMP file.

Comment: The PNG/JPEG/TGA is not an option since it need to use external library (libpng, libjpeg, WIC, DevIL) which bloat & slow down the program that I create.